# ShareKit - sharing on Facebook still show the demo app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sharekit

I've got a problem in using the share kit function.

I've got a button and its IBAction like below.

But the problem is when I tab on button, it shows an ActionSheet with Facebook, Twitter and Pocket, I select Facebook, got authenticated, and then it redirects me to the ShareKit demo app!

```
- (IBAction)moreSharing:(id)sender { 
{
// Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Welcome to mywebsite"];

// Get the ShareKit action sheet
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the action sheet
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

I have checked my Xcode project solution file and already removed and deleted the Examples folder. I have no idea where the demo app comes from.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you subclassed DefaultSHKConfigurator and edited the settings? You can find out how it's done in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use the ShareKit's demo app Facebook URL scheme for your app. You can see it in ShareKit-info.plist (and your app-info.plist). You should use your own app id from Facebook.